# url or content as a variable in the header of the page

Tags: php, image, header

I am designing a site where external links form various are being shown on my page. I am using

```
$url=$_GET['url'];
$website_data = file_get_contents($url);
echo $website_data;
```

so essentially a user would click on a hyperlink which is something like `www.test.com/display_page.php?url=http://www.xyz.com/article/2.jpg`

My page, list_of_images.php, typically has a list of images with href for each image as above on the page and when any image is clicked it would go to display_page.php, which would show our banner on the top of this page, some text and then this image beneath that. This image could be from any website.

I am currently sending the url directly and grabbing it using GET. I understand that users/hackers can actually do some coding and send commands for the url variable and could break the server or do something harmful and so i would like to avoid this method or sending the url directly in the header. what is the alternate approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make sure the url starts with `http://` or `https://`:

```
if(preg_match("`^https?://`i", $_GET['url']))
// do stuff
```

You may also want to make sure it isn't pointing anywhere internal:

```
if(preg_match('`^https?://(?!localhost|127\.|192\.|10\.0\.)`i', $_GET['url']))
// do stuff
```

Rather than a big dirty regex, you could go for a more elegant host black-list approach, but you get my drift...

Answer (score 1):

The safe approach is to use a fixed set of resources stored in either an array or a database, and the appropriate key as a parameter.

```
$ress = Array('1' => 'http://www.google.com/', ...);

$res = $ress[$_GET['res']];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i cannot use a database or an array since the images and the url keep changing dynamically every minute.

Comment: Even if they change every second, I don't understand why you can't use a database.

Comment: @Scorpion King: The only other way is to only allow relative URLs, and clean them very carefully so as not to allow `/`.  Make sure it matches something like this: `/^[a-z0-9-_]+\.(jpg|jpeg)$/i`.

Comment: @Scorpion King: But anyway, it would still be best to do as @Ignacio says, and keep a fixed set.  How is the set changing?  Do you change it, or do you have any control over it?

Comment: @Ignacio: for this project we do not have any database setup and would not want to use one.

Comment: @jonah: i did consider using preg_match and checking the url, but i certainly wanted to know if there was any other way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Try POST....

Try doing this using POST method